# Webkit crashing on WinCE

Tags: javascript, c, webkit, windows-ce

I am working on a port of Webkit for WinCE 6 (ARM) and am running into Javascript issues.

- Code base: https://github.com/masali-hp/webkit
- Javascript Engine: JavascriptCore

I am using Masali's code base. When loading a page which contains jQuery the application crashes (can't get a full crash log) and have tracked the issue down to when the code hits the section to do with the JIT and the ctiTrampoline.

At the decode call in JITCode.h it blows up with an exception in code that is not instrumented and the following error code is spit out of the OS 0xDFFF0123.

Comment: I think this has to do more with c than javascript.

Comment: Well I was trying to point out that it is an issue when there is Javascript on the page being visited. A pure HTML/CSS page will render perfectly.